# React test component with children

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs

How can I test a React component that has "children"?

I have a Center component, which basically wraps an element (children)

This is the Center component:

```
const Center = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='center'>
    <div className='center__content'>{children}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Below is the code I have tried, but I got an error "Invalid attempt at destructure non-iterable instance"

```
function setup () {
  const props = {}
  const renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer()
  renderer.render(<Center {...props}><p>Hi</p></Center>)
  const output = renderer.getRenderOutput()

  return {
    props,
    output
  }
}

describe('(Components)', () => {
  describe('Center', () => {
    it('should render correctly', () => {
      const { output } = setup()

      expect(output.type).to.equal('div')
      expect(output.props.className).to.equal('center')

      const [ div ] = output.props.children // Error triggered here, how do I access this 'center__content' ?
      expect(div.props.className).to.equal('center__content')

    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A React component's children `this.props.children` can be one of two types:

- an array
- a single child (in the instance that there is no child)

See the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html) for more information

Therefore the de-referencing statement you have is causing an error as this.props.children is not an Object with a `div` attribute defined.

I'd advise inspecting what `output.props.children` looks like by doing `console.log(output.props.children)`.

Your tests on `output.props.children` should be something like:

`expect(this.props.children.type).to.equal('p'); // The child element you passed into your Center component.`